# Border between divs

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and was wondering how to put a border between `div`s in this case in the middle between green and blue?

[image]

Html:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="left">

</div>
<div class="right">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  background: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1024px;
   min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 550px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 550px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a property called `border`, basic usage goes sth like `.class{border-left:2px solid #ff00ff;}`. Pay attention that this will influence the sizing of your elements.

Comment: Thats tha thing, if I put the border-left: 1px;  it resizes everything and these divs aren't next to each other. Green div has float left and width 30%, the blue one has float:right and width 70%

Comment: @Kimvais see the edit history for a much more cryptic and gimmetehcodez version of this question.

Comment: @m90 - box-sizng *does* work in IE8 - http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: @Danield: just saw this myself when writing the answer, but now it's too late to edit the comment.... Thanks for the hint anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

The easiest one would be using `box-sizing: border-box;` which will make the border part of the element's box. Therefore 30% + 70% will still add up to a 100%. Yet, this is only **[partially supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)**.

```
.right, .left{
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5hRd/) for this one.

Another approach you could use would be using absolute positioning instead of floating (therefore causing a simple overlap of the elements taken out of the document flow):

```
.right, .left{
  float: none;
  position: absolute; //make sure the parent element has relative positioning here
}
.right{
  right: 0;
}
.left{
  left: 0;
}
```

See [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5hRd/1/)

Then, there's also calc (which isn't too [well supported](http://caniuse.com/calc)), that lets you subtract one pixel off your percentage value:

```
.left{
   width: -webkit-calc(30% - 1px);
   width: -moz-calc(30% - 1px);
   width: calc(30% - 1px);
}
.right{
  width: -webkit-calc(70% - 1px);
  width: -moz-calc(70% - 1px);
  width: calc(70% - 1px);
}
```

Again, [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r5hRd/2/)

Comment: Upvote because this the only solution that I can agree with - using display table hacks is clunky, and outline is not used for the purpose of adding borders.

Answer (score 0):

```
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 550px;
  background: blue;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 550px;
  background: green;
}
```

Comment: But they aren't side by side anymore. I added the html and css and second picture. Probably my css is sh** because I don't have any experience wirking with css but you have to learn sometime!

Comment: Outline shouldn't be used as a border replacement, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS table layout. Check out that <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/HGsqZ/)</kbd>

Supported by IE8+, Cross-Browser.

**HTML:** (very clean and simple)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (easy to maintain and Cross-Browser)

```
.wrap {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 1024px;
    min-height: 400px;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.left, .right
{
    display: table-cell;
    min-height: 550px;
}
.right {

    width: 70%;
    background-color: blue;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
.left {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: green;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```